# SP13: Opening PowerPoint Presentation into Slide Show

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I am using SP13 and wanting to upload a PowerPoint presentation to document library.  After I upload the document to the library I would like for the presentation to open into a slide show.  I have performed the following steps to achieve the outcome, but no success.  Can anyone help me find a way to have my PowerPoint presentation open into a slide slow once a user clicks on the link?

Thanks for your help.

Steps done:

1. Uploaded the document to the library and changed the advance settings to open in the browser.
2. Uploaded the document and copy the URL from the library for the document
3. Tried changing the settings on the presentation within PowerPoint.  No success neither.

BY the way...the check in and out feature is on the PowerPoint slide.  Not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for Office Web Apps. 
They allow PowerPoint documents to open in the browser. Then you can click "Start Slide Show" in the top menu. If so, I recommend reading  [Use Office Web Apps with SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855124(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it would translate into SP, but if you save a PowerPoint file as .pps it will open as a slide show.